# Running the rest code after condition is met

Tags: javascript

please how can i make the second if condition run after i is greater than 9

```js
var i = 0;
var x = document.querySelector(".start");
x.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (i < 10) {
        console.log(i);
            i++;
    }
})
if (i === 10) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<button class="start">start</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the check inside of the event callback and check if the value is ten, then return early.

Otherwise increment `i` and make the wanted output.

```js
var i = 0;
var x = document.querySelector(".start");
x.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (i === 10) return;
    i++;
    if (i < 10) {
        console.log(i);
    } else {
        console.log('ten');
    }
})
```

```html
<button class="start">start</button>
```